# php: recursive function/query

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a table:

```
officer|user
------------
25     |22
25     |3
25     |16
16     |21
16     |13
```

When I sign in as officer 25 then need to list down all daily records of users(22,3,16,21,13),maybe in future will have thousand or million records.

This is my recursive function:

```
function getRootUser($currentUser,&$array,$count){
   $getRootSQL=base_executeSQL("SELECT estaf_staff_user_id from estaf_staff where estaf_staff_officer=".$currentUser." AND estaf_staff_user_id!=0");

   if (base_num_rows($getRootSQL)!= 0)
   {
      while($rootdata_row = base_fetch_array($getRootSQL))
      {
         $currentUser=$rootdata_row["estaf_staff_user_id"];//1
         $array[]=$currentUser;
         $count = $count + 1;
         getRootUser($currentUser,$array,$count);   
      }
   }
   return $array;}
```

And this is my list out function:

```
function eleav_listRequest($currentUser,$page, $record ,$search){

  getRootUser($currentUser,$array,0);

  $searchs = explode(" ", $search);

  $SQL =  "SELECT * FROM eleav_leave  " ;
  $countSearch = 0;

  foreach ($searchs as &$value) 
  {
    if ($countSearch == 0)
    {
        if (count($array)!=0)
        {
            $SQL .="WHERE (eleav_leave_user='".$array[0] ."' ";

            for($i=1;$i<count($array);$i++) 
                $SQL.="OR eleav_leave_user=".$array[$i]." ";
            $SQL.=") AND ";
        }
        else
            $SQL.="WHERE (eleav_leave_user='') AND ";

    }
    else
    {
        $SQL .=" AND ";
    }
    $SQL .=  "      (eleav_leave_code LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eleav_leave_user IN (SELECT base_u_id FROM base_users WHERE base_u_name LIKE '%".$value."%') OR
                    eleav_leave_from_date LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eleav_leave_to_date LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eleav_leave_application_date LIKE '%".$value."%' OR
                    eleav_leave_status LIKE '%".$value."%') ";
        $countSearch ++;

}//....below continue with my print out data layout
```

Currently it is still ok to work, but I wonder can my recursive function survive once my records increase more. Cos sometimes when I try to load the data it will come with error maximum execution time.

Can anyone help to improve or a better recursive?Thanks